# Quiz App API crashing due to Nil coming through my JSON Decoder, but not sure why it is nil instead of my data

Tags: ios, json, swift

Below is my code, I am getting the Implicitly Unwrapped Nil error, which I know is because of the self.QQs = QQs! line due to the !. I am unsure though why QQs is nil, as the url i am pulling from is not (as you can see in the link, which shows the public JSON i am using). Why is QQs nil?

```
struct QQ: Codable, Identifiable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case question
        case answer1
        case answer2
        case answer3
        case answer4
        case logo
    }
    
    var id = UUID()
    var question: String
    var answer1: String
    var answer2: String
    var answer3: String
    var answer4: String
    var logo: String
}

class ReadData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var QQs = [QQ]()
    
    init(){
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData()  {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/641f82dcace6f33a22fbec99")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let QQs2 = try? JSONDecoder().decode([QQ].self, from: data!)
        self.QQs = QQs!
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Don't use `try?`. Use a full `do/catch` block and `try`. Add `print(error)` inside the `catch` block then you will know what the actual problem is instead of ignoring the error.

Comment: Also, never use `Data(contentsOf:)` with remote URLs. Use `URLSession` to load the data from the URL.

Comment: you do not receive an array from the server. You do not receive
 anything like a `QQ`. Put `https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/641f82dcace6f33a22fbec99` into your browser, then copy and paste the json data,
 into https://app.quicktype.io/ and the correct model structs will
 be generated for you (adjust them to your needs). You can of course do all this by hand, and it gives you what you already have,
 errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not receive an array from the server, and you do not receive
anything like a `QQ` from the server, that is why your app crashes from your decoding.

Put `https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/641f82dcace6f33a22fbec99` into your browser, then copy and paste the raw json data,
into https://app.quicktype.io/ and the correct models will
be generated for you.

Adjust the generated code, and you endup with these models, as
shown in the example code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = DataManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let qData = model.response?.record.questiondata.data {
                List(Array(qData.keys), id: \.self) { key in
                    VStack {
                        Text(qData[key]?.answer1.text ?? "no data")
                        Text(qData[key]?.answer2.text ?? "no data")
                        Text(qData[key]?.answer3.text ?? "no data")
                        Text(qData[key]?.answer4.text ?? "no data")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await model.loadData()
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class DataManager: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var response: APIResponse? = nil
    
    func loadData() async  {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/641f82dcace6f33a22fbec99") {
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                response = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct APIResponse: Codable {
    let record: Record
    let metadata: Metadata
}

struct Metadata: Codable {
    let id: String
    let metadataPrivate: Bool
    let createdAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case metadataPrivate = "private"
        case createdAt
    }
}

struct Record: Codable {
    let questiondata: QuestionData
}

struct QuestionData: Codable {
    var data: [String : Quest]
    
    struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?
        
        init?(stringValue: String) {  self.stringValue = stringValue  }
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.data = [:]
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)
        container.allKeys.forEach { key in
            if let theQuest = try? container.decode(Quest.self, forKey: key) {
                self.data[key.stringValue] = theQuest
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct Quest: Codable {
    let question: String
    let answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4: Answer
}

struct Answer: Codable {
    let logo, text: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case logo
        case text = "Text"
    }
}
```